# Resolve bash variable containted in another variable

Tags: string, bash, replace

I have code like that:

```
TEXT_TO_FILTER='I would like to replace this $var to proper value
                in multiline text'
var=variable
```

All I want to get is:

```
TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED="I'd like to replace this variable to proper value"
```

So I did:

```
TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED=`eval echo $TEXT_TO_FILTER`
TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED=`eval echo $(eval echo $TEXT_TO_FILTER)`
```

Or even more weirder things, but without any effects. 
I remember that someday I had similar problem and I did something like that:

```
cat << EOF > tmp.sh
echo $TEXT_TO_FILTER
EOF
chmod +x tmp.sh
TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED=`. tmp.sh`
```

But this solution seems to be to much complex.
Have any of You heard about easier solution?

Comment: TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED=``eval echo $TEXT_TO_FILTER`` seems to work for me

Comment: It would work fine for me as well, but I have more complex TEXT_TO_FILTER contents (many lines, chars like < > etc.). In that way simple eval won't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash expand variable in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049057/bash-expand-variable-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [security reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) it's best to avoid `eval`. Something like this would be preferable:

```
TEXT_TO_FILTER='I would like to replace this %s to proper value'
var=variable
printf -v TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED "$TEXT_TO_FILTER" "$var"
# or TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED=$(printf "$TEXT_TO_FILTER" "$var")
echo "$TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED"
```

Comment: It is the solution I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED="${TEXT_TO_FILTER//\$var/$var}"
```

or, using perl:

```
export var
TEXT_AFTER_FILTERED="$(echo "$TEXT_TO_FILTER" | perl -p -i -e 's/\$(\S+)/$ENV{$1} || $&/e')"
```

This is still more secure than eval.