# Expand $BASH_COMMAND preferably without eval

Tags: bash

As part of an error handling function, I need to report the currently executing command when an error is trapped.  The bash $BASH_COMMAND string contains the command, but with nested non-expanded variables.  I would like to avoid using eval if there is a better way.

Given these input variables:

```
path1="a/a/a"
path2="b/b/b"
BASH_COMMAND='mycommand "$path1" $path2'
```

Produce this output variable:

```
expanded='mycommand a/a/a b/b/b"
```

This works with eval, but I am concerned this may be unsafe:

```
expanded=$(eval echo "$BASH_COMMAND")
```

EDIT: as chepner explained in the comment below, this question is not answered by [Bash expand variable in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049057/bash-expand-variable-in-a-variable) because the string must be parsed and may contain multiple nested variables.

Comment: That question assumes you have just the name in the variable, not a string with one or more parameter expansions embedded in it. For this problem, you'd need to do some additional non-trivial parsing to isolate the parameter names first.

Comment: What about if you have spaces in your variables?  How should quoting be handled then?

Comment: Very, *very* nontrivial. I've seen POSIX sh parsers available (albeit none of them written in shell), but I've never seen a fully complete parser for bash syntax available in bash.

Comment: Frankly, it's a lot more feasible to just dump all variables defined and let the person doing the debugging sort out which ones are pertinent.

Comment: ...and the easy approaches will execute`$(command-substitutions)` and the like, which are inherently side-effecting operations.

Comment: Looks like bash doesn't support what you want. `set -x` and parse stderr? I know, horrible...

Comment: note: I foolishly downvoted your question the first time I saw it, because I didn't get it (perhaps add an actual usage example, I doubt it's a common known feature). please edit the Q so I can upvote. thx.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, one can do better than parsing stderr -- with bash 4 or later, you can redirect `set -x` output to an arbitrary file descriptor with `BASH_XTRACEFD`, so the content can be directed to an arbitrary location or process.

Comment: Thx. Nice topic! @ElliottFrisch: can you remove your close vote?

Comment: I'm also looking for a nice solution. `eval echo "${BASH_COMMAND}"` works for expanding variable but strips quotes :-(

Comment: If you want to evaluate something, you have to use `eval`. If you fear `eval`, you should also fear any alternative doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file with the command and source that file then remove it. Here is a working script:

```sh
path1="a/a/a"
path2="b/b/b"

mycommand() {
  echo $@
}

MY_COMMAND='mycommand "$path1" $path2'

echo "$MY_COMMAND" > ./temp.sh
source ./temp.sh
rm ./temp.sh
```

BTW, I renamed `BASH_COMMAND` to `MY_COMMAND` because it is an [internal environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/q/513932/1121112) containing the currently executed command with its arguments. Instead of writing to `temp.sh`, you can also generate a file using `RANDOM` inside the `/tmp/` directory:

```sh
path1="a/a/a"
path2="b/b/b"

mycommand() {
  echo $@
}

MY_COMMAND='mycommand "$path1" $path2'
RAND_NUM=$RANDOM

echo "$MY_COMMAND" > /tmp/temp-$RAND_NUM.sh
source /tmp/temp-$RAND_NUM.sh
```