# Indirect expansion in bash variables for very long paths

Tags: bash, shell, path

Drawing on a [*broadly similar answer,*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14050187/1655567) I would like to indirectly expand path variable to create another path.

## Example

```
# Files directory
long_path='/very/long/path/that/I/dont/want/to/type'
archive_path='${long_path}/Archive'

# Print paths
echo -e "Long path: ${long_path}.\nArchive path: '${!archive_path}'."
```

### Results

As shown below only the **`${long_path}`** is printed correctly.

```
Long path: /very/long/path/that/I/dont/want/to/type.
Archive path: ''.
```

Comment: This is non-sense... what is `dta_fld`? why do you (think you) need indirect expansion?

Comment: Still non-sense: `${archive_path}` expands to `${long_path}/Archive` (verbatim), and `${!archive_path}` will expand to the expansion of the variable named `${long_path}/Archive`... but there's no such variable! did you understand indirect expansion? why do you need indirect expansion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables in `bash` do not expand on single quotes, you need to double-quote them.

```
archive_path="${dta_fld}/Archive"
```

And from seeing your example code, you don't seem to have a candidate that needs indirect expansion. In-direct expansion works on a case like below, where the variable you are trying to expand is pre-defined

```
foo='bar'
bar='zoo'
printf "%s\n" "${!foo}"
```