# How to recursively substitute variable for a path in bash variable in configure.ac?

Tags: bash, autotools, autoconf

I am dealing with autotools and here is the situation:

By default *libdir* is set to **'${exec_prefix}/lib'** with *exec_prefix* set to **'${prefix}'** and *prefix* set to **'/usr/local'**.

Key here recursion and at first level *libdir* variable contain another variable **and** a following path.

So how to convert *${libdir}* into a variable containing **'/usr/local/lib'** ?

Info : all 3 (libdir, exec_prefix, prefix) can change according configuration.

Consider the following files:

configure.ac

```
AC_PREREQ([2.59])
AC_INIT([test], [0.0.0] )
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE()
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([test.cpp])
AC_LANG([C++])
AC_PROG_CXXCPP
AC_PROG_CXX

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile path.conf])

AC_MSG_NOTICE([">>> Before ac_output prefix=${prefix}"])
AC_OUTPUT
AC_MSG_NOTICE([">>> after ac_output prefix=${prefix}"])
```

Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = test.cpp
```

test.cpp

```
int main()
{}
```

path.conf.in

```
@libdir@
```

Then after invoking :

```
aclocal && autoconf && automake -a --foreign && ./configure
```

configure log show:

```
configure: ">>> Before ac_output prefix=NONE"
...
...
...
configure: ">>> after ac_output prefix=/usr/local"
```

And generated file path.conf contains

```
${exec_prefix}/lib
```

The goal is to have a variable containing the expanded version of the path to be used in a *path.conf.in* so autotools generate *path.conf* with that expanded path.

---

Edit: Bash only solution

Digging related topics and helped by @Aserre answer, I manage to do the following with a regex.

```
while expr match "${libdir}" '^.*\$.*$' 1>/dev/null;
do
    echo ">${libdir}"
    libdir="$(eval echo ${libdir})"
done
```

Which means : While *$libdir* contain one **$** expand with *eval*.

But does not work in configure.ac script before AC_OUTPUT

Comment: `exec_prefix` is the *literal* string `${prefix}`? Why not (and I admit, I am ignorant about autotools) just wait until `prefix` has a value to set `exec_prefix=${prefix}`?

Comment: @chepner : _echo ${libdir}_ return _${exec_prefix}/lib_

Comment: Yes, @chepner, and that is deliberate, so that the user can override the installation prefix when they run `make install`.  The `${prefix}` is ordinarily expanded by `make`.

Comment: @Nelstaar, can you perhaps explain why you want to do this?  Because a prettier (and better) solution *might* be to do nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash expand variable in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049057/bash-expand-variable-in-a-variable)

Comment: @John Bollinger, question edited, but I just figured out that $prefix and $exec_prefix are set to NONE by defaut before AC_OUTPUT call. :_(

Comment: Although the proposed dupe target asks about Bash specifically, the answers include both Bash-specific and general POSIX-conforming alternatives.

Comment: @Nelstaar, maybe it's time for a [mcve], then.  I have worked rather a lot with the Autotools, and I have never seen the `$prefix` or `$exec_prefix` reset automatically.  I have especially not seen them reset to "NONE" -- if you do not specify them at all, then the default for `$prefix` is `/usr/local`, and this is what normally ends up being used in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The goal is to have a variable containing the expanded version of the path to be used in a *path.conf.in* so autotools generate *path.conf* with that expanded path.

The Autotools provide special handling for default values of the installation-directory variables, in order to enable the user to specify or override the installation prefix at `make install` time:

```
make install prefix=/my/special/prefix
```

What you propose to do will break that.  If a user specifies a different installation prefix at the installation stage than they tell `configure` (or that they let `configure` choose by default) then you will end up with a broken installation.

The best way to do address problems like this is to build the configuration file under `make`'s control, at `make install` time, instead of doing it at configuration time.  If the project uses Automake, then that might mean something like this:

```
install-data-local:
    $(SED) -e 's,[@]libdir[@],$(libdir),' path.conf.in > $(sysconfdir)/path.conf
    chmod 0644 $(sysconfdir)/path.conf
    chown root:root $(sysconfdir)/path.conf

uninstall-local:
    rm $(sysconfdir)/path.conf
```

You can of course substitute more output variables than that if you like.  It's pretty close to what `configure` does itself.

And of course, if you do it this way then you do not need to worry about performing extra expansions.

Comment: I wished there was a solution at configure time. thx @John Bollinger

Comment: I don't think any sane autoconf user has ever needed this feature and yet it causes endless hassle for everyone else.

Comment: I don't follow, @Rich.  Which feature are you talking about, and how does it cause trouble for anyone?

Comment: @Nelstaar Is a [build-time solution](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Scripts.html) gonna help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are 100% sure of the content of the `${exec_prefix}` variable, you could use the following line to achieve what you want :

```
libdir="$(eval echo ${exec_prefix})"
```

---

Note that in a lot of cases, the use of eval is discouraged. Here, if the user has overriden the content of the variable `exec_prefix`, for instance with `exec_prefix='a; rm -rf /'`, all the code written will be executed.

If you are in total control of your environment (i.e. you are certain of the value of the variables when you launch the script), there should be no problem, otherwise be wary of the potential side effects

Comment: Of course content of libdir is subject to change. Like when invoking ./configure --libdir=/what/ever/path