# Bash - Expanding a variable into another variable name

Tags: bash, variable-expansion, parameter-expansion

Let's say I have these variables:

```
VAR_A=resultA
VAR_B=resultB
X=A
```

I want to get the value of `VAR_A` or `VAR_B` based on the value of `X`.

This is working and gives `resultA`:

```
VAR="VAR_$X"
RESULT=${!VAR}
```

My question is, is there a one-liner for this?

Because [indirection expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) doesn't seem to work if it is not the wole name of the variable which is expanded. I tried:

```
RESULT=${!VAR_$X}
RESULT=${!"VAR_$X"}
```

...and a lot of other combinations, but it always write "bad substitution"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash expand variable in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049057/bash-expand-variable-in-a-variable)

Comment: @CorentinLimier no, I'm sorry, this is not the same question, because the X variable is included into another variable as a string, and indirection expansion doesn't work in that case. That is the whole point of my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a shorter way when using the bash 2 notation of `${!var}`.
For reference, the "new" bash 2 notation is `value=${!string_name_var}` and the "old" notation would be: `eval value=\$$string_name_var`.

You could just use the old notation to make it work like you wanted:

```
eval RESULT=\$"VAR_$X"
```

Reference: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#BASH2REF

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using an associative array, at least on recent versions of Bash:

```
declare -A var=(
    [A]=resultA
    [B]=resultB
)
x=A
result="${var[$x]}"
echo "$result"  # -> resultA
```

Comment: I know this would be a better option, but I'm in a context where it is not possible (env vars declared in Gitlab-CI - no arrays allowed).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
RESULT=$(eval echo \$VAR_$X)
```

The `\` in front of the `$` makes it be treated literally.

Comment: Even shorter `eval RESULT=\$VAR_$X`